# mod_rewrite debugging shows unexpected REWRITE_COND order of events

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I noticed something unexpected when debugging rewrite rules: it seems that the order of events is that Apache processes a rule, and then retroactively applies the preceding conditions to it. Is this as-designed, or am I misinterpreting something?

Here's a simple example of a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file. It doesn't really do anything useful -- it's just an example.

```perl
    RewriteEngine on
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . / [L]
```

And here is the resulting trace (heavily redacted for readability)

```
[...redacted...] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test.html
[...redacted...] pass through /test.html
[...redacted...] [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/test.html -> test.html
[...redacted...] [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'test.html'
[...redacted...] [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/test.html' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[...redacted...] [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/test.html
```

Notice that "RewriteCond" gets applied *after* the pattern gets applied. The ultimate result is a pass-through, which is correct (since the file does, in fact exist), so it doesn't really matter. I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems that the order of events is that Apache processes a rule, and then retroactively applies the preceding conditions to it. Is this as-designed, or am I misinterpreting something?

Yes, that is how it works.

The RewriteRule has to match first. Only if that is the case, the RewriteCond-itions are evaluated. If these then match, the rewrite is performed.

This is not so clearly mentioned on the manual page that describes the syntax for RewriteCond and -Rule; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond just says,

> The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, **and** if these conditions are met.

Now you *could* imply the processing order from this maybe (if you read it in “logical” order, left to right), but it is not very explicit.

But https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex says,

> Regex Back-Reference Availability
> One important thing here has to be remembered: Whenever you use parentheses in Pattern or in one of the CondPattern, back-references are internally created which can be used with the strings $N and %N (see below). These are available for creating the Substitution parameter of a RewriteRule or the TestString parameter of a RewriteCond.
>
> Captures in the RewriteRule patterns are (counterintuitively) available to all preceding RewriteCond directives, **because the RewriteRule expression is evaluated before the individual conditions.**

(Highlight at the end by me.)

So in that place you find this behavior explicitly mentioned.